# Go AST: get all structs

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to be able to get all structs. For example, assume we have:

```
type SomeType struct {
    // ..
}

type someType2 struct {
    //..
}
```

Our code.

```
structs := getAllStructs(srcPath)  //gets SomeType and someType2
```

I have some code which finds all .go files in srcPath and does `parser.ParseFile` on it.

Is there a way using [ast](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast), [parser](https://pkg.go.dev/go/parser), [packages](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/packages), etc... I can get all structs at once at any scope? What if there is a struct which is not package scoped? How can I get struct declarations also inside the function? Like:

```
func main() {
    
    type someType3 struct {
        //..
    }

}
```

Comment: not strings, but *ast.StructType or actual struct types itself. I am looking for types declared at any scope.

Comment: all files in srcPath. I have some code which finds all .*go in srcpath and then does parser.ParseFile on each one of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Parse](https://pkg.go.dev/go/parser#ParseFile) each file of interest. [Inspect](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#Inspect) the file to find struct types.

```
fset := token.NewFileSet()
f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, fileName, nil, 0)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Collect the struct types in this slice.
var structTypes []*ast.StructType

// Use the Inspect function to walk AST looking for struct
// type nodes.
ast.Inspect(f, func(n ast.Node) bool {
    if n, ok := n.(*ast.StructType); ok {
         structTypes = append(structTypes, n)
    }
    return true
})

// The slice structTypes contains all *ast.StructTypes in the file.
```